# NodeJS - Mongoose return object from find?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing an node.js API with Mongoose,

But for the purpose of a task, I want to get the object as a variable from my find,

so I have this :

```
exports.get_info = function(_id) {

  Session.findById(_id, function(err, session) {
  if (err)
    res.send(err);

  console.log (session); // the object is good
  return session; // trying to return it
   });
 };
```

but When I call :

```
      session_ = sessions.get_info(id);
```

here `session_` is undefined ...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right way to do it is :

```
exports.get_info = function(_id,callback) {

  Session.findById(_id, function(err, session) {
  if (err)
    res.send(err);

  console.log (session); // the object is good
  callback(null,session); // trying to return it
   });
 };
```

in this way, you can get the session like this :

```
sessions.get_info(id,function(err,session){
if(err) console.log(err);
console.log(session);
});
```

Comment: you can also return the error variable and print it in the calling function eg : **callback(err)**

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose model `find` it's an sync function, you can't get result immediately. You should use callback or much better solution - promise (mongoose supports promises):

```
exports.get_info = function(_id) {
  return Session.findById(_id);
 };

 get_info(/* object id */)
   .then(session > console.log(session))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```